# Remove nested attribute in json file without structs

Tags: json, rust

Assuming I have a big JSON file.
My goal is to just remove a nested field within that JSON and write a new file.

```rust
use serde_json::Value;
use serde_json::Map;

fn main() {
    let data = r#"{
                    "name": "John Doe",
                    "age": 43,
                    "nested":{
                        "to.be.removed": [
                          "+44 1234567",
                          "+44 2345678"
                        ],
                        "other": "important fields"

                    }
                  }"#;

    let mut map :Map<String, Value> =serde_json::from_str(data).expect("failed to read file");
    // how do i remove  "to.be.removed"?


}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3c9725d12e50516c8472bd2ddb108514)

I cannot figure out how to remove such a nested attribute.

Since the json is quite complex, i have to stick to a Map as i am not interested in structs. Fetching the value of nested renders me a `Value`. I would just like to change the value into a map to then insert like this
`map.insert(String::from("nested"), nested);`.

Comment: I would move all of the string allocations out of the json object and construct any needed structs with those allocations minus what you don't need after the fact.

Comment: So as far as i understant MeetTitan, i shall use a struct for the nestest part?
This would be just 3 attributes, which sound feasible.
The file is a ~3k lines  json file, with dozens of attributes. I omitted the rest for complexity reason to showcase my issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to use the [JSON Value type API](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html) to traverse into children elements of the root JSON object until you reach the items to remove or insert.

```
let data = r#"{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 43,
    "nested":{
        "to.be.removed": [
          "+44 1234567",
          "+44 2345678"
        ],
        "other": "important fields"

    }
}"#;
let mut map: Map<String, Value> = serde_json::from_str(data)
    .expect("failed to read file");

// get to the nested object "nested"
let nested = map.get_mut("nested")
    .expect("should exist")
    .as_object_mut()
    .expect("should be an object");

// now remove the child from there
nested.remove("to.be.removed");
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aa28469ea1e0dde9a21012afa10c4951)

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. I could not manage to convert the `Value` to the `Map` the nested object to be usable as a map. Thank you very much!